# iphone push didn't receive (Window Server/IIS/PHP)

Tags: php, ios, iis, apple-push-notifications

First of all, it is not a problem about certification or dev/distribution.

I used distribution certification, and server url -> gateway.push.apple.com:2195

I tested in my local server(apache2), and it work!

However, in my real server(IIS/Window server) I used same php code, same certification file(.pem), and same iphone application... etc, it printed "Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered", but my phone didn't receive message.

One suspect is, I tested my certification file(.pem) by cmd command line 'openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert xxxx.pem', It returned "Verify return code: 20 (unabled to get local issuer certificate). So I found solution that downloaded entrust certification(.cer) and did "openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert xxxx.pem -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer", and it returned 'Verify return code :0'. So I added my php code 'stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'CAfile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');', but it didn't work same problem.

Comment: Have you checked whether the port 2195 is open in your server?

Comment: @PrasadRajapaksha Yes. Is it right that in window firewall added outbound, inbound port 2195, 2196?

Comment: You can try sample PHP script to check whether the port is open or not. And in your push script usually it give an error if it can't send the push message.

Comment: @PrasadRajapaksha where can I can sample php script?

Comment: <?php

$site = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 2195;

$fp = fsockopen($site,$port,$errno,$errstr,10);
if(!$fp)
{
echo "Cannot connect to server";
}

else{
echo "Connect was successful - no errors on Port ".$port." at ".$site;
fclose($fp);
}

?>

Comment: @PrasadRajapaksha it just printed 'PHP Warning:  fsockopen():  in "my file path"'

Comment: @PrasadRajapaksha nothing. just warning